# Is it possible to create a custom admin page for users?

Tags: admin, users

I want to greatly restrict the user's authority in the website. I don't want to give the user access to the admin console but I do want to allow the user to edit their username, email, and password.

Everything I've done so far is custom (lots of wp_query) and so I haven't used any plugins yet and would like to keep it that way if I can. Therefore, is it possible to create a custom page where the user can edit their username, email, and password?

Comment: Hi, i worked a lot about this. The best way to do it is to use a pluing like ultimate member or pie register. If you code it yourself, you will probably end up with a security problem.

Comment: WP allows custom log-in forms that still posts the form through the core wp-login.php file. You don't think we can create a custom form that edits the user's password through whatever core php file WP uses to edit passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show only some Admin page items to a user-type, this page might get you started: https://www.johnparris.com/how-to-restrict-access-to-menu-items-in-the-wordpress-admin/ . Not much detail there, but might get you started.

You would then limit access based on the person's login level (Editor, Subscriber, etc). Or create a new login-level, and use that to limit access.

To get started on admin access levels and what they can do, start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities  That page contains links to plugins that might do what you need (or that can provide you a starting point to creating your own plugin)